# Advanceddatagrid becomes empty while hiding the columns in the visible area

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

We are developing an advanceddatagrid in flex 3 such that the columns in that datagrid can be hidden when a particular state is called.

While doing a sample we faced an issue that, we have certain columns in our datagrid, and we scrolled to last column ,and then now we are hiding the all the columns which are in the visible area. After this , all columns are disappeared. here i have attached the snapshots.[image: Datagrid at initial stage]

After clicking the Hide columns button , the advanceddatagrid becomes 
[image]

Please help me on this issue.

Note: we have tried by using validateNow() while hiding each column. but that created a lot of preoblem with our item editors.

My sample code snippet:

```
protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{

myADG.columns[7].visible = false;
myADG.columns[8].visible = false;
myADG.columns[9].visible = false;
myADG.columns[10].visible = false;

}
```

My Sample Code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.core.mx_internal;
            use namespace mx_internal;
            [Bindable]
            private var dpFlat:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
                {Region:"Southwest", Territory:"Arizona", 
                    Territory_Rep:"Barbara Jennings", Actual:38865, Estimate:40000}, 
                {Region:"Southwest", Territory:"Arizona", 
                    Territory_Rep:"Dana Binn", Actual:29885, Estimate:30000},  
                {Region:"Southwest", Territory:"Central California", 
                    Territory_Rep:"Joe Smith", Actual:29134, Estimate:30000},  
                {Region:"Southwest", Territory:"Nevada", 
                    Territory_Rep:"Bethany Pittman", Actual:52888, Estimate:45000},  
                {Region:"Southwest", Territory:"Northern California", 
                    Territory_Rep:"Lauren Ipsum", Actual:38805, Estimate:40000}, 
                {Region:"Southwest", Territory:"Northern California", 
                    Territory_Rep:"T.R. Smith", Actual:55498, Estimate:40000},  
                {Region:"Southwest", Territory:"Southern California", 
                    Territory_Rep:"Alice Treu", Actual:44985, Estimate:45000}, 
                {Region:"Southwest", Territory:"Southern California", 
                    Territory_Rep:"Jane Grove", Actual:44913, Estimate:45000}
            ]);

            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {

                myADG.columns[7].visible = false;
                myADG.columns[8].visible = false;
                myADG.columns[9].visible = false;
                myADG.columns[10].visible = false;

            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:Panel title="AdvancedDataGrid Control Example"
              height="75%" width="75%" layout="horizontal"
              paddingTop="10" paddingBottom="10" paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10">

        <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="myADG" 
                             width="50%" height="60%" 
                             dataProvider="{dpFlat}" horizontalScrollPolicy="on" >        


            <mx:columns>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Region" width="100" headerText="1"/>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Territory" width="100" headerText="2" visible="true"/>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Territory_Rep"
                                           headerText="3" width="100" visible="true"/>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Actual" width="100" headerText="4" visible="true"/>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Estimate" width="100" headerText="5" visible="true"/>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Territory_Rep"
                                           headerText="6" width="100" visible="true"/>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Actual" width="100" headerText="7"/>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Estimate" width="100" headerText="8"/>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Territory_Rep"
                                           headerText="9" width="100"/>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Actual" width="100" headerText="10"/>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Estimate" width="100" headerText="11"/>
            </mx:columns>
        </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
        <mx:Button label="Hide Columns" click="button1_clickHandler(event)" />

    </mx:Panel>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: I don't know if I am understanding you correctly, are you trying to hide columns that are currently in view, all columns or column headers or what?

Comment: I added the sample code snippet. i hide the columns which are in view(by keeping horizontal scroll position at last).

Comment: What does tracing the dataProvider say after you have hidden the columns? Have you tried also using invalidateDisplayList()-method after hiding them?

Comment: yes, i tried but it also went in vain.

Comment: Sorry, this is just shooting in the wild but what if you turn all of them visible again after setting them to false? Did you check that dataProvider trace? Where is the data coming from?

Comment: It's realy so... I have tried to debug the ADG component to find the error. All looks good... The only way I can advice you is to set "myADG.horizontalScrollPosition = 0;" BEFORE hiding the columns. It works good, but the user have to scroll after all to the right position.

Comment: @Anton: Already we have this option as temporary solution. But our customers won't accept this behaviour.

Comment: If you can post a simple application that shows the problem, we can try it out. This all seems rather weird, but frankly, I still don't understand what you're doing, or why the work around of setting the `horizontalScrollPosition` to 0 makes it behave differently.

Comment: @Sunil: i have shared the sample code.

Comment: @vengatesh Similar to what Anton suggested, how about setting `myADG.horizontalScrollPosition = 3` before you make the columns invisible? Horizontal scroll position in the grid is based on columns, so setting it to 3 will make it remain on the last column that is visible (this may vary based on the size of your grid). This is still a hack, it probably won't help. The problem seems to be that after you make some columns invisible, that the grid is not adjusting it's `maxHorizontalScrollPosition` value (which in this case is always 8).

Comment: @vengatesh, let us know if you find a solution to this please. Its a definite bug in the DG

Comment: @Brian :Still I haven't find any solution for that. Instead of that I used manual logic for that.
First i took the horizontal scroll position before hiding columns, after taking the horizontal scroll poistion , i changed the horizontal scroll position to zero and i hid the columns, after hiding the columns ,i again set the horizontal scroll position with already taken value.Temporarily i am using it.

Comment: @vengatesh I had a little go at it too, but couldn't find any cause except when removing the % height width constraints - but then that just points to the horizontal scrolling that you spotted anyhow. Workaround is needed I suppose!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your `horizontalScrollBarPosition` to 0 after hidding your last columns, maybe the ADG just didn't handle well your case >_<